# How to make my linux-2.6.24.4 to identify a hard disk with serial mode on intel 3201 mainboard

Tags: sata

How to make my linux-2.6.24.4 to identify a SATA hard disk on an intel 3201 mainboard?

I have pre-load modules `libata.ko ahci.ko scsi_mod.ko sd_mod.ko`, but it doesn't work on `intel 3210` mainboard. On an intel 5000P mainboard it works.

Any modules I should to load for support intel 3210 sata hard disk support?

Comment: Any luck yet with this?

Comment: I don't this question is "useful" anymore. 6 year old problem with 6 year old kernel, most likely related to mainboard settings in BIOS/EFI, poster has not been seen since Q.

Answer (score 0):

Both are supported by the normal sata drivers. I think, the most probable cause of your problem is with the ahci settings.

1. Is the ahci set up in the bioses of both mainboards?
2. If yes, and further doesn't go, maybe it could be some bug. In this case, try to set ahci off in the 3210, and try to use the non-ahci driver. Maqybe it won't be so optimal, but at least it will work.

If you need further help, an `lspci` output helped a lot.